# How to get rid of a repeating word in this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know what kind of problem this is called and couldn't find something related to this on the site. I am trying to make a function that prints out the first letter of the word on the first line then the next two letters and so on. However, I am not sure on how to prevent repeating the complete word. For example in the word 'bar', it should go

```
b
ba
bar
ba
b
```

but my function repeats bar twice. Thanks!

```
a= []

def letters():
    x = input("Enter a string")
    count = 0
    for c in x:
        count +=1
    y = 0
    while y <= count:
        z = (x[:y])
        a.append(z)
        y += 1
    negWords = a[::-1]
    for words in a:
        print (words)
    for words in negWords:
        print (words)
```

Comment: Sorry, I left out the a at the top. It is supposed to be a list so I can add the strings and print it out from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be doing some unnecessary work for simply wanting to print something. You can make use of `len` to get the length of the word, without having to go through a loop to get the size.

Also, collecting the data in a list seems unnecessary.

To stick to the nature of your approach with the while loop, you can go through the entire length of the word and *back* again until "0". So, to me, I see that as twice the length of the word. With that in mind, that would be my control for the while loop. I would simply then check for when my incrementer reaches about the length of the word, and start going backwards from there:

```
w = "bar"
l = len(w)

i = 0
while i <= l*2:
    if i > l:
        print(w[:(l - i)])
    else:
        print(w[:i])
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
b
ba
bar
ba
b
```

Comment: Ok thanks it works! But what is the purpose for the l*2? I'm not sure on how you got that.

Comment: @Alex. The `l*2` gives us twice the length of the word, because if you look inside the loop, we are checking for when `i` becomes greater than `l`. The reason for this, is because as we go through the loop, by the time we get to `i = 3`, we would have already outputted: `b`, `ba`, `bar`. Now, we want go go back down to get the next part of our output: 'ba`, 'b'. So this is where we have to complete counting to twice the word. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense now, but how does the while loop know in the if and else statements that the L now carries the value of L*2 instead of just L as written?

Comment: Because of the last line inside the loop that does the `i += 1`. It increments each time in the loop by `. So when I check `i > l`, it will always see at what point `i` is greater than `l`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
negWords= a[:-1:-1]
```

This will not include the full word a second time

Also, your code could use a lot of cleanup. For example:

```
count = len(x)
```

Makes more sense than what you have